# SQL query for difference between two tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables: `Bucket1` and `Bucket2`.

Columns in both the tables are: `ToyId` and `Price`

```
Bucket1
-----------------------------
ToyId        |    Price
-----------------------------
A            |    10
B            |    20
C            |    30
D            |    40
E            |    50
-----------------------------

Bucket2
-----------------------------
ToyId        |    Price
-----------------------------
D            |    45
E            |    50
F            |    60
G            |    70
H            |    80
-----------------------------
```

I want a resultant table as below:

```
Result
-----------------------------------------------------------
ToyId        |    PriceTab1    |    PriceTab2   |   Diff
-----------------------------------------------------------
A            |    10           |    NA          |    NA
B            |    20           |    NA          |    NA
C            |    30           |    NA          |    NA
D            |    40           |    45          |    5
E            |    50           |    50          |    0
F            |    NA           |    80          |    NA
G            |    NA           |    90          |    NA
H            |    NA           |    100         |    NA
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Above table contains:
1) Common Toys (D, E)

2) Toys in Bucket1 but not in Bucket2 (A, B, C)

3) Toys in Bucket2 but not in Bucket3 (F, G, H)

4) Difference in price where applicable (D, E)

Is it possible to achieve this in a single query ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example of `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(b1.ToyId, b2.ToyId)  AS ToyId,
    b1.Price                      AS PriceTab1,
    b2.Price                      AS PriceTab2,
    (b2.Price-b1.Price)           AS Diff
FROM
    Bucket1 AS b1
  FULL JOIN
    Bucket2 AS b2
      ON b1.ToyId = b2.ToyId ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Tables

```
create table b1 (
  t_id varchar(1),
  price int
  );

  create table b2 (
  t_id varchar(1),
  price int
  );

 insert into b1 (t_id, price)
             values
             ('a', 10),('b', 20),('c', 30),('d', 40),('e', 50);
insert into b2 (t_id, price)
             values
             ('d', 45),('e', 50),('f', 60),('g', 70),('h', 80);
```

select

```
select t_id, sum(price1), sum(price2) 
from 
  (select t_id, price as price1, null as price2 from b1
   union all 
   select t_id, null as price1, price as price2 from b2) res
group by t_id;
```

left the diff calculation out of scope

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c669fc/6